# Able to set value of private variable by public property without setter

Tags: c#, .net

How is this code able to compile and run error free?

```
private void queueToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Class name MDPlayer
        Playlist.QueueList.Add(tempPlayList[songView.SelectedIndex]);
        Playlist.GetQueue = null;
        QueueCombobox.Items.Clear();
        foreach (PlayListData pld in Playlist.QueueList)
        {
            QueueCombobox.Items.Add(pld.Track);
        }
    }
class Playlist
{
private static List<PlayListData> queueList = new List<PlayListData>();

    public static List<PlayListData> QueueList
    {
        get { return queueList;}
    }
}
```

How am I able to add to queueList that is private through the public property QueueList that doesn't even have a setter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are able to call methods on the return value of a property getter.

Your property getter returns a `List<>`.  `List<>` defines the `Add` method.  Thus you can call the `Add` method on the `List<>` that you asked for.

Note that you *can not* assign a new value to the `listQueue` from outside the `PlayList` class because it is [`private`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).
Also, you can not assign a new value to the `ListQueue` property because it has no setter accessor.
This will fail:  `PlayList.QueueList = new List<PlayListData>();`

Answer (score 1):

Because you're adding to the list via the getter. You're not setting the underlying private variable to anything. You can do `QueueList.Add()`, but not `QueueList = newList`.

Answer (score 0):

When you get a value from the getter, it returns the whole class and that class is alterable.  You only need a setter when you want to set the whole variable to an entirely different class.

**Summary**
You only need to use a setter when setting the whole variable.

**Can**

```
Playlist.QueueList.Add(tempPlayList[songView.SelectedIndex]);
```

**Cannot**

```
Playlist.QueueList = new List<PlayListData>();
```

Comment: property getters return objects, not classes.  Similarly, setter accessors only work with objects as well, not classes.